# MongoDB secondary node does not become primary when other nodes are stopped

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4

I want to cluster MongoDB by using a replica set. I have created a three-node replicaset (rs0,rs1,rs2), and run the DBs in parallel with no issues. But when I shut down any two instance (one primary and secondary), the remaining secondary member is not made the primary, instead it remains as a secondary.

Step1:

- rs0: primary
- rs1: secondary
- rs2: secondary

Every thing is ok. When

Step2:

- rs0: stopped
- rs1: stopped
- rs2: secondary  *(This is not promoted to primary)*

Why?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. If you want to run with only one node, restart that node without replica set switch.

> If a majority of the replica set is inaccessible or unavailable to the
>   current primary, the primary will step down and become a secondary.
>   The replica set cannot accept writes after this occurs, but remaining
>   members can continue to serve read queries if such queries are
>   configured to run on secondaries.

Read these resources for more details:

1. [Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)
2. [mongo replica set to single server](https://serverfault.com/questions/389876/mongo-replica-set-to-single-server)
3. [Voting in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597372/voting-in-mongodb)

Comment: What if this happens in production? if all secondary nodes fail, then can't anybody perform insert operation anymore?